# calculate column value in sql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table in a MySQL db that looks like that:

`SELECT * FROM pi;`

`Employee_id    Year
1000           2014
1000           2015
1001           2014
1002           2014
1002           2015
1003           2015
1004           2015`

When I run the following query:

`SELECT Employee_id, MIN(Year)
FROM pi
GROUP BY Employee_id;`

I get:

`Employee_id    Year
1000           2014
1001           2014
1002           2014
1003           2015
1004           2015`

Now I want to add a new column to the original table values that should have a '0' if the value of the Year for the row equals the MIN(Year) for the Employee_id or a '1' if it doesn't. I've tried:

```
SELECT Employee_id, MIN(Year),
 (CASE WHEN(SELECT MIN(Year) FROM pi WHERE Employee_id = Employee_id < Year) THEN '0' ELSE '1' END) New
FROM pi
GROUP BY Employee_id;
```

And this produces:

`Employee_id    Year    New
1000           2014     0
1001           2014     0
1002           2014     0
1003           2015     0
1004           2015     0`

On the other hand, when I tried:

```
SELECT Employee_id, MIN(Year),
  (CASE WHEN(SELECT MIN(Year) FROM pi 
WHERE Employee_id = Employee-id
GROUP_BY employee_id < Year) THEN '0' ELSE '1' END) New
FROM pi;
```

I got just:

`Employee_id    Year    New
1000           2014     1`

I've tried a bunch of additional querys, but all of them rendered error messages or the same results than those two, so I'm kind of stuck here. Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join ond the min table

```
select t.Employee_id, t.min_year
  , case when pi.year = t.min_year then 0 else 1 end as my_check
from pi inner join (

    SELECT Employee_id, MIN(Year) as min_year
    FROM pi
    GROUP BY Employee_id
)  t on t.Employee_id = pi.Employee_id
```